# Results only shown if user number is in blocking table

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a database table full of user status updates. I want to output all these results, providing that the user that posted that status has not been blocked.

The **WHERE** clause IS being met.. but for some reason it's also deciding to only output status updates where the 'user id' is present within one of the tbl_blocking columns.

Obviously, if that user doesn't appear in the blocking table at any point (has never been blocked, or blocked anyone) their status should still be shown.

*How can I overcome this? Where am I going wrong?*

```
//Get status results
            $sql = "SELECT 

            tbl_status.id as statID, 
            tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
            tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
            tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
            tbl_status.date as statDATE,

            tbl_users.id as usrID, 
            tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
            tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,
            tbl_users.postcode as usrPOSTCODE,

            tbl_blocking.id as blockID,
            tbl_blocking.user as blockUSER,
            tbl_blocking.blocking as blockBLOCKING,
            tbl_blocking.date as blockDATE,
            tbl_blocking.active as blockACTIVE

            FROM tbl_status 

            INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
            INNER JOIN tbl_blocking ON tbl_users.id = tbl_blocking.user

            WHERE 
            tbl_status.deleted = '0'
            AND tbl_blocking.active = '0'
            AND tbl_blocking.user != :who
            AND tbl_blocking.blocking != :who

            ORDER BY 
            tbl_status.date desc

            LIMIT 200

            ";
```

Comment: Please add some basic schema otherwise its hard to help.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and expected output, to help us better understand your requirements.

Comment: Well, if users don't appear within the blocking table, they should have their status updates shown too. But currently it only shows updates  for users that are in the blocking column and meet the WHERE clause. Why aren't the other updates being shown for users that are not being blocked and passing the WHERE clause?

Comment: I think I see the issue on the left join. You need to have an additional where clause such as tbl_blocking2.id IS NOT NULL, otherwise it will include those records. Still include schema.

Comment: Currently I expect to see 10 updates to be shown. But I'm only being shown 3. Those 3 are the results for users that are in the blocking table and passing the WHERE clause. It needs to return users not within the blocking table too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get rows that have no match in the joined table. And then if you want to be able to select particular rows in the joining table, you have to include a specific `NULL` test to keep that row as well.

```
        $sql = "SELECT 

        tbl_status.id as statID, 
        tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
        tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
        tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
        tbl_status.date as statDATE,

        tbl_users.id as usrID, 
        tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
        tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,
        tbl_users.postcode as usrPOSTCODE,

        tbl_blocking.id as blockID,
        tbl_blocking.user as blockUSER,
        tbl_blocking.blocking as blockBLOCKING,
        tbl_blocking.date as blockDATE,
        tbl_blocking.active as blockACTIVE

        FROM tbl_status 

        INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking ON tbl_users.id = tbl_blocking.user

        WHERE 
        tbl_status.deleted = '0'
        AND (tbl_blocking.user IS NULL
            OR (tbl_blocking.active = '0'
                AND tbl_blocking.user != :who
                AND tbl_blocking.blocking != :who))

        ORDER BY 
        tbl_status.date desc

        LIMIT 200

        ";
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I extend this a little further to ensure that if :who wrote a status, it will always be shown no matter what. (If the user that's logged in wrote the status, let them see it, always)

Comment: Also, I've just realised... the way the where clause is currently wrote, it doesnt matter who is blocking who, as long as blocked.active = 1, nobody will see the status by them. whether the user logged in is blocking them or not

Comment: I'm not sure what the columns in tbl_blocking represent, so it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are joining against the blocking table. This means only users in the blocking table AND the users table will be shown. You want to left join BOTH tbl_blocking and tbl_blocking2 it seems. I'm not sure of your schema, as to why you join twice on the same table.

For example:

```
User  join Blocking

1,2,3       2,3

will return ids (assuming select user.id, blocking.id): 
2,2
3,3

This will OMIT user 1 as blocking does not contain id 1.

User  left join blocking

1,2,3          2,3

will return

1, null (this will be null since blocking does not contain an id of 1)
2, 2
3, 3 

This will include id 1 that you are missing.
```

Here is something to explain joins better:
[Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Excerpt of your mysql:

```
FROM tbl_status 
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking ON tbl_users.id = tbl_blocking.user
```

Since status and user appears to be a 1 to 1 record a join there should be fine. The left join of blocking on user is necessary. This will provide all records of the user table no matter what is in the blocking table. I have included a resource to look at that will explain it further. I also can start a chat on here if that will help you.

Comment: Ah, I can remove blocking2 content now. It was a different method I was using to try and get it working. I'll amend my question to show you my original code.

Comment: There, the code should be correct-ish now. I've struggled for a while to understand joins. Maybe that's the issue. I've joined 3 tables on the common field tbl_users.id (or equivalent)

Comment: I've updated my question before your update. I'll look at your amended, but it might help you.

Comment: I join users onto status to get the name of the user that wrote the status. Then i join the users to the blocking table to see which users are being blocked.

Comment: So I should just left join?

Comment: Let me see if i can write up a quick query.

Comment: A left join is what you need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48907/discussion-between-shawn-and-elaine-adams)